# How to progamatically get the directory in where libraries are installed with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I asked a question about why my libraries were found in every compiler except visual studio. Well, it turns out that in visual studio, when you build a library or anything with it, they are set within a Debug or Release folder.

Looking at this zlib.cmake file:

```
SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY PROPERTY "EP_BASE" ${ep_base})
SET(zlib_GIT_TAG "origin/master")

# If CMake ever allows overriding the checkout command or adding flags,
# git checkout -q will silence message about detached head (harmless).
ExternalProject_Add(Zlib_external_download
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/madler/zlib.git"
  GIT_TAG ${zlib_GIT_TAG}
  PATCH_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_DIR ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=${CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE}
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=ON
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STATIC=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STATIC=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
    -DDO_ZLIB_MANGLE:BOOL=${DO_ZLIB_MANGLE}
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(Zlib_external_download BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(Zlib_external_download SOURCE_DIR)

SET(Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR} CACHE PATH "")
SET(Zlib_INCLUDE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR} CACHE PATH "")

add_library(Zlib STATIC IMPORTED)

MESSAGE(STATUS "Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR: ${Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR}")
```

I set the library directory to the Binary Directory of the external project, and the include directory to the Source Directory of the external project. This works for gcc, MinGW, and Xcode. However, since the external project is built within Visual Studio, the actual libraries and dll's are placed in the `${BINARY_DIR}/Debug}` or `${BINARY_DIR}/Release}` depending on how you build the project.

As a band-aid, I have put:

```
if(MSVC)
  if(EXISTS ${Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR}/Debug)
    set(Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR ${Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR}/Debug)
  elseif(EXISTS ${Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR}/Release)
    set(Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR ${Zlib_LIBRARY_DIR}/Release)
  endif()
endif()
```

This is a horrible solution as both Debug and Release could be built and if Release were to be chosen to be built while Debug was already built, it will link with the Debug libraries instead of the Release libraries.

Is there a way to find where the libraries are so I can set the paths correctly so it will cross compile cleanly? Or is there a way to tell whether Debug or Release is being built so I can link the paths with `if(MSVC)`?

Comment: Maybe [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) can help you.

Comment: @Lasall, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE will not give you the build type of Visual Studio. When CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is called within CMake, it is returned blank, or empty.